# EF Core Query Not Applying any Where conditions to Nested Includes

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

We had attempted to optimize an especially large EF Core SQL query that runs over 500 separate SQL statements when lazy-loading by using `Include/ThenInclude` on the tables that were being queried separately.  We quickly found that we couldn't do everything in one large query because of the sheer number of joins, so subsequently added `AsSplitQuery` to the version with the includes.  This appeared to work until we ran it against out production dataset, where we discovered that some queries used for the included tables did not include *any* filter criteria on the subqueries it was joining, resulting in scans with millions of records and queries executing for several seconds.

Here is an example of one such query.  You can see that the second sub-query it is joining against does not have the where clause, and therefore executes an extremely inefficient scan before being joined on the id.

```sql
SELECT [t0].[OrderId], [t0].[Branch], [t0].[DeliveryAddressId], [t0].[DeliveryContactId], [t0].[IsBackOrderShipment], [t0].[IsDropShipment], [t0].[MerchandiseTotal], [t0].[OriginalInvoiceNumber], [t0].[OriginalOrderId], [t0].[PhysicalOriginId], [t0].[ShipmentDate], [t0].[ShipmentTotal], [t0].[VendorPurchaseOrder], [t].[Id], [t].[OrderId], [t0].[OrderId0], [t0].[Branch0], [t0].[OrderId1], [t0].[Branch1], [t0].[OrderId2], [t0].[Branch2], [t0].[Id], [t0].[CarrierId], [t0].[FreightTerm], [t0].[FreightTermChargeType], [t0].[ServiceLevelId], [t0].[ServiceTypeId], [t0].[ShipMode], [t0].[ShipModeReason], [t0].[Value], [t0].[Weight], [t0].[Cube], [t0].[Density], [t0].[FullPallets], [t0].[PartialPalletHeight], [t0].[Value0], [t0].[Weight0], [t0].[Attention], [t0].[DeliveryName], [t0].[PostalAddressId]
FROM (
    SELECT [s].[Id], [o].[OrderId], [s].[OrderDate]
    FROM [SalesOrder] AS [s]
    LEFT JOIN [OrderHeader] AS [o] ON [s].[Id] = [o].[OrderId]
    WHERE (((([s].[Tenant] = N'param') AND ([s].[CustomerAccount] = N'param')) AND ([o].[CustomerPurchaseOrder] = N'param')) AND ([s].[OrderDate] >= '2021-07-27')) AND (([s].[OrderTypeId] = 1) OR ([s].[OrderTypeId] = 2))
    ORDER BY [s].[OrderDate] DESC, [s].[Id] DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
) AS [t]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [o0].[OrderId], [o0].[Branch], [o0].[DeliveryAddressId], [o0].[DeliveryContactId], [o0].[IsBackOrderShipment], [o0].[IsDropShipment], [o0].[MerchandiseTotal], [o0].[OriginalInvoiceNumber], [o0].[OriginalOrderId], [o0].[PhysicalOriginId], [o0].[ShipmentDate], [o0].[ShipmentTotal], [o0].[VendorPurchaseOrder], [o1].[OrderId] AS [OrderId0], [o1].[Branch] AS [Branch0], [o1].[CarrierId], [o1].[FreightTerm], [o1].[FreightTermChargeType], [o1].[ServiceLevelId], [o1].[ServiceTypeId], [o1].[ShipMode], [o1].[ShipModeReason], [o2].[OrderId] AS [OrderId1], [o2].[Branch] AS [Branch1], [o2].[Value], [o2].[Weight], [o3].[OrderId] AS [OrderId2], [o3].[Branch] AS [Branch2], [o3].[Cube], [o3].[Density], [o3].[FullPallets], [o3].[PartialPalletHeight], [o3].[Value] AS [Value0], [o3].[Weight] AS [Weight0], [d].[Id], [d].[Attention], [d].[DeliveryName], [d].[PostalAddressId]
    FROM [OrderShipment] AS [o0]
    LEFT JOIN [OrderShippingSpecification] AS [o1] ON ([o0].[OrderId] = [o1].[OrderId]) AND ([o0].[Branch] = [o1].[Branch])
    LEFT JOIN [OrderShippingCartonization] AS [o2] ON ([o1].[OrderId] = [o2].[OrderId]) AND ([o1].[Branch] = [o2].[Branch])
    LEFT JOIN [OrderShippingPalletization] AS [o3] ON ([o1].[OrderId] = [o3].[OrderId]) AND ([o1].[Branch] = [o3].[Branch])
    INNER JOIN [DeliveryAddress] AS [d] ON [o0].[DeliveryAddressId] = [d].[Id]
) AS [t0] ON [t].[OrderId] = [t0].[OrderId]
ORDER BY [t].[OrderDate] DESC, [t].[Id] DESC, [t].[OrderId], [t0].[OrderId], [t0].[Branch], [t0].[OrderId0], [t0].[Branch0], [t0].[OrderId1], [t0].[Branch1], [t0].[OrderId2], [t0].[Branch2], [t0].[Id]
```

The EF query is built with the includes all being added to the root `DBSet` and then the where conditions applied after that:

```cs
context.SalesOrders
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .Include(order => order.OrderHeader)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShipments)
            .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShipmentMarkups)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.TaxCharge)
    .Include(order => order.OrderHeader)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShipments)
            .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShippingSpecification)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShippingFeatures)
    .Include(order => order.OrderHeader)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShipments)                        
            .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShippingSpecification)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShippingCartonization)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShippingCartonizationContainers)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShippingCartonizationContainerItems)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShippingCartonizationContainerItemHazardousPackagings)
    .Include(order => order.OrderHeader)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShipments)                        
            .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShippingSpecification)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShippingCartonization)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShippingCartonizationContainers)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShippingCartonizationContainerFeatures)
    .Include(order => order.OrderHeader)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShipments)                        
            .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShippingSpecification)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShippingPalletization)
                .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShippingPalletizationFeatures)
    // A bunch more includes
    .Where(order => order.Tenant == tenant)
    .Where(order => order.CustomerAccount == account)
    // Several other where clauses based on input parameters
    .OrderByDescending(order => order.OrderDate)
    .ThenByDescending(order => order.Id)
    .Skip(paging.LastRecord)
    .Take(paging.PageSize)
```

When this query runs against our Production data set, we saw execution times exceeding 20s, and analyzing the query plan revealed the scans in the specific subquery I pointed out above as being the majority of the time, since they had no filters applied.  As such, we have removed the `Include/ThenInclude` statements entirely and now the execution is back down to under 1s, but with many smaller queries executing instead the lower number of queries with more joins we had intended.  This makes the application very chatty with the DB during this operation, and I'm not sure why the includes didn't work as we expected.  Is there a way to get EF Core to generate that second subquery in the `INNER JOIN` with a `WHERE` clause so that it executes efficiently?

EDIT:

This is the query I would **like** EF to generate for me, where the additional tables are joined in on the second subquery so the `WHERE` clause can be included.  In SSMS, this version of the query runs 100x faster that then version EF is currently generating.

```sql
SELECT [t0].[OrderId], [t0].[Branch], [t0].[DeliveryAddressId], [t0].[DeliveryContactId], [t0].[IsBackOrderShipment], [t0].[IsDropShipment], [t0].[MerchandiseTotal], [t0].[OriginalInvoiceNumber], [t0].[OriginalOrderId], [t0].[PhysicalOriginId], [t0].[ShipmentDate], [t0].[ShipmentTotal], [t0].[VendorPurchaseOrder], [t].[Id], [t].[OrderId], [t0].[OrderId0], [t0].[Branch0], [t0].[OrderId1], [t0].[Branch1], [t0].[OrderId2], [t0].[Branch2], [t0].[Id], [t0].[CarrierId], [t0].[FreightTerm], [t0].[FreightTermChargeType], [t0].[ServiceLevelId], [t0].[ServiceTypeId], [t0].[ShipMode], [t0].[ShipModeReason], [t0].[Value], [t0].[Weight], [t0].[Cube], [t0].[Density], [t0].[FullPallets], [t0].[PartialPalletHeight], [t0].[Value0], [t0].[Weight0], [t0].[Attention], [t0].[DeliveryName], [t0].[PostalAddressId]
FROM (
    SELECT [s].[Id], [o].[OrderId], [s].[OrderDate]
    FROM [SalesOrder] AS [s]
    LEFT JOIN [OrderHeader] AS [o] ON [s].[Id] = [o].[OrderId]
    WHERE (((([s].[Tenant] = N'param') AND ([s].[CustomerAccount] = N'param')) AND ([o].[CustomerPurchaseOrder] = N'param')) AND ([s].[OrderDate] >= '2021-07-27')) AND (([s].[OrderTypeId] = 1) OR ([s].[OrderTypeId] = 2))
    ORDER BY [s].[OrderDate] DESC, [s].[Id] DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 20 ROWS ONLY
) AS [t]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [o0].[OrderId], [o0].[Branch], [o0].[DeliveryAddressId], [o0].[DeliveryContactId], [o0].[IsBackOrderShipment], [o0].[IsDropShipment], [o0].[MerchandiseTotal], [o0].[OriginalInvoiceNumber], [o0].[OriginalOrderId], [o0].[PhysicalOriginId], [o0].[ShipmentDate], [o0].[ShipmentTotal], [o0].[VendorPurchaseOrder], [o1].[OrderId] AS [OrderId0], [o1].[Branch] AS [Branch0], [o1].[CarrierId], [o1].[FreightTerm], [o1].[FreightTermChargeType], [o1].[ServiceLevelId], [o1].[ServiceTypeId], [o1].[ShipMode], [o1].[ShipModeReason], [o2].[OrderId] AS [OrderId1], [o2].[Branch] AS [Branch1], [o2].[Value], [o2].[Weight], [o3].[OrderId] AS [OrderId2], [o3].[Branch] AS [Branch2], [o3].[Cube], [o3].[Density], [o3].[FullPallets], [o3].[PartialPalletHeight], [o3].[Value] AS [Value0], [o3].[Weight] AS [Weight0], [d].[Id], [d].[Attention], [d].[DeliveryName], [d].[PostalAddressId]
    FROM [OrderShipment] AS [o0]
    LEFT JOIN [OrderShipping] AS [o1] ON ([o0].[OrderId] = [o1].[OrderId]) AND ([o0].[Branch] = [o1].[Branch])
    LEFT JOIN [OrderShippingCartonization] AS [o2] ON ([o1].[OrderId] = [o2].[OrderId]) AND ([o1].[Branch] = [o2].[Branch])
    LEFT JOIN [OrderShippingPalletization] AS [o3] ON ([o1].[OrderId] = [o3].[OrderId]) AND ([o1].[Branch] = [o3].[Branch])
    INNER JOIN [DeliveryAddress] AS [d] ON [o0].[DeliveryAddressId] = [d].[Id]
    INNER JOIN [OrderHeader] AS [o] ON [o0].[OrderId] = [o].[OrderId]
    INNER JOIN [SalesOrder] AS [s] ON [s].[Id] = [o].[OrderId]
    WHERE (((([s].[Tenant] = N'param') AND ([s].[CustomerAccount] = N'param')) AND ([o].[CustomerPurchaseOrder] = N'param')) AND ([s].[OrderDate] >= '2021-07-27')) AND (([s].[OrderTypeId] = 1) OR ([s].[OrderTypeId] = 2))
) AS [t0] ON [t].[OrderId] = [t0].[OrderId]
ORDER BY [t].[OrderDate] DESC, [t].[Id] DESC, [t].[OrderId], [t0].[OrderId], [t0].[Branch], [t0].[OrderId0], [t0].[Branch0], [t0].[OrderId1], [t0].[Branch1], [t0].[OrderId2], [t0].[Branch2], [t0].[Id]
```

Comment: Just read [Split queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries)

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I've read that several times now.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.  We addressed the warning about skip/take as directed in the article, and I don't see anything that mentions impacts to the `where` clause.  We're using EF 6.0, by the way.

Comment: So, `AsSplitQuery()` do not work for you? Or you want to reverse engineer EF Core Eager loading?

Comment: Hmm, and what `where` condition exactly do you expect? All your `where` conditions are on tables which are not in the `join` subquery. The `join` actually connects (and filters) tables with `where` and other tables. The problem most likely is not the `where` and `joins`, but the `order by`. Also this doesn't look like split query.

Comment: @IvanStoev Good point.  I suppose what I would like to happen is that the second subquery is filtered down to the Order IDs that match the first subquery.  The way a typical join would work if they weren't subqueries.  I think this would be achievable with a CTE if you were writing the query by hand, what I'm not sure about is if there's any way to get EF to generate this query (or something equivalent) for me, as the existing query it generates returns over a million records for that second subquery, only to then join it down to the records for one Order ID.

Comment: @IvanStoev Actually, I added an example above of what I would like EF to generate for the second subquery.  I'm not sure how to make it do that, but the query I just added via the edit is 100x faster and returns the correct data, and all I had to do was add the joins back to the required tables so I can include the `where` clause on the second subquery.

Answer (score 1):

The way you can add `where` to your joins is covered in [Filtered includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include).

In you case you would be doing something like this where applicable:

```
context.SalesOrders
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .Include(order => order.OrderHeader)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShipments)
            .ThenInclude(s => s.OrderShipmentMarkups.Where(osm => osm.Property == specificValue))
                .ThenInclude(s => s.TaxCharge)
```

In the case where you can't get that to work exactly how you want you can try passing your own SQL to `FromSql` as covered in [SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries)

Personally in my experience I find that once you get more than half a dozen `Include`/`ThenInclude` the performance is quite slow, one option to improve performance is adding `AsSplitQuery` as you have done, another option is adding a `Select` to specify only the columns you want returned in the query and you could probably taco girl it and use both if you want to :)